# "Блять" против "блядь"

Tags: правописание

Существует ли всё-таки междометие "блять" или нет и уместно ли вообще говорить об ошибках в словах ненормативной лексики?

Comment: It's just the noun *блядь* used as an interjection, like *мама*, *батюшки* etc. Why do you think the spelling change would be justified?

Comment: [Related post](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/4249/551).

Comment: My vision is that the difference in spelling marks the difference in usage. I agree with this, for example: [link](https://danieldefo.ru/threads/%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C.7085/)

Comment: Seems like a forced-meme kind of quasi-rule to me. *Блядь* is *блядь* is *блядь*, interjection or noun. Spelling it with a т is either a sign of trying to be casual and edgy, or a last-ditch effort at visual euphemisation. Anything else is, ultimately, the same kind of grassroots prescriptivism as the insufferable *крайний раз*.

Comment: Or the insistence on dotting all your Ёs.

Answer (score 12):

Не существует. *Блять* — это визуальная рифма с *ебать!* и *твою мать*, и отсюда, наверно, возникло представление о том, будто "так оно пишется, когда междометие", но нет, оно воспринималось и воспринимается как "слово с ошибкой", даже когда с этой ошибкой употребляется намеренно.

Comment: I think it is because it has been reinterpreted as a verb.

Comment: @Anixx I doubt that.

Answer (score 5):

Полностью соглашусь с ответом Николая Ершова, но добавлю еще ответ на вторую часть вопроса. А почему, собственно, может не быть уместным говорить об ошибках в словах ненормативной лексики? Они также являются частью корпуса языка и подчиняются тем же правилам, что и все остальные слова. И, к слову, "блядь" до середины 19 века было литературным словом, а изначально вообще значило всего-то "ошибка"/"ошибаться" и "лгать".

Comment: Это слово значило - "та, кто заблуждается, блудит", от слова "блуд", третьего склонения.

Comment: Дмитрий, а вы, случайно, "блядити" и "блудити" не путаете? "Блядити" - "ошибаться, заблуждаться, пустословить, лгать". "Блудити" - "блуждать", постепенно перенеслось на "блуждающие половые связи". Весь комплекс значений "блудства" перешел к "блядству" только к XVIII веку, а сами слова были известны еще до XIII века.