# Правда ли что слово "блядь" происходит от польского "błąd"?

Tags: этимология, мат

В [недавнем вопросе](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7816/551) о правильности написания слова "блядь" в комментариях разгорелась дискуссия по поводу этимологии этого слова. Были высказаны две версии заимствования. Например, что само это слово заимствовано из польского языка:

> Слово "блядь" происходит от польского "błąd", что означает "ошибка". В свою очередь błąd происходит от старославянского корня блѫдъ, который сохранился и в русском и в польском языке, однако польский вариант ближе всего к оригиналу и по произношению, и по смыслу.

Или даже из иврита (בלי יד):

> Оно происходит от слова на иврите, означающее "женщина ходящая в одиночку". Многие русские бранные слова и слова криминального арго происходят из иврита. Причиной этому является то, что в девятнадцатом веке многие бандиты были евреями *(видимо имеется в виду в Одессе, где процветала контрабанда)* и пытались скрыть смысл своих разговоров от полицейских, многие из которых понимали идиш, но не знали иврит.

Какая из этих версий верна?

UPD: Google Translate переводит "ивритский" вариант как "без рук", без каких-либо намеков на "женщину", так что этот вариант происхождения вызывает большие сомнения.

Comment: А как же [праиндоевропейское _bhloti_](http://anaga.ru/rumat.htm) - "течь, менструировать"

Comment: Есть вариант, что слово "блаать" означало в древности звук мотылька, сгорающего в пламени свечи.

Comment: Related: [http://ec-dejavu.ru/b/Bljad.html#tabu](http://ec-dejavu.ru/b/Bljad.html#tabu)

Comment: @Vilmar Спасибо за ссылки!

Comment: к апдейту: да, это означает "без руки", и толковалось (в посте в ЖЖ, который я сейчас почему-то нагуглить обратно не могу) как "без держащего за руку". Отчего и говорю, что притянуто за уши сильнее обычного.

Comment: вот что точно нет - что польское слово "błąd" по произношению ближе старославянскому - хотя бы потому что твёродое л уже пару веков минимум как перешло в w )))

Comment: Нашел целый [сборник ивритских заимствований](http://jerusalem-temple-today.com/for/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=25437) ;) Вот пара цитат: "Женщина, являющаяся в обществе без опоры на мужскую руку – это «бли яд»=«בלי יד». А как же будет наоборот: женщина, опирающаяся на мою руку? «леяди»= «לידי» = ЛЕДИ!"

Comment: вариант польского происхождения притянут за уши очень и очень сильно. а вариант с ивритом - тем более. говорят, что матерные слова имеют татаро-монгольское происхождение, но я в это не верю... не доказано...

Comment: владея ивритом, никогда не встречал указанных слвосочетаний в коннотации, которую они якобы приобрели в русском... кроме того, если в русский что-либо из иврита и попадало, то через идиш, потому что с носителями живого иврита у носителей русского прямых контактов быть не могло в силу исторических причин, евреев-талмудистов можно исключить, так как они в быту на иврите не общались... подтвердить или опровергнуть возможную связь с идишем способен только знаток идиша, коим я не являюсь

Comment: Для полноты обсуждения :)....
https://pikabu.ru/story/proiskhozhdenie_slova_quotblyadquot_1629403

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Версия об ивритском происхождении — типичная фольклорная этимология, причем даже сильнее обыкновенного притянутая за уши. Возможно, это шутка, кем-то принятая всерьез. При этом близкое по смыслу слово ивритского происхождения в криминальном арго присутствует — это слово *хуна*.

С польским очевидно присутствует ровно обратная ситуация: это в современном польском есть ругательство *bladź*, фонетически заимствованное из русского и не учитывающее, что польский когнат имел бы носовой гласный. Из-за чего, собственно, слово *блядь* в принципе до этого не могло быть заимствовано в русский из польского позже X века, когда носовые исчезли в русском, иначе фонетика это бы отразила — ср. *В**ен**грия* от польского *Więgry*. Утверждение, что в такой глубине веков некое слово пришло в древнерусский именно из древнепольского, в отсутствие источников кажется весьма произвольным, тем более что никаких трудностей чисто русская этимология этого слова не представляет.

И уж точно этим польским словом не могло быть *błąd* — у меня сложилось впечатление, что предложивший его весьма приблизительно себе представлял, как оно звучит, и был сбит с толку графическим подобием. *Błąd* — это *блуд*, и как когнат, и как тот вид, который приняло бы слово в гипотетическом случае заимствования из польского в X веке или ранее.

Резюмируя, можно в шутку (**в шутку**, подчеркиваю, наученный горьким опытом) сказать, что версия о происхождении слова *блядь*, сперва в форме мн.ч. *бляди*, от английского бранного эпитета *bloody* представляется куда убедительнее и "польской" гипотезы, и "ивритской".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, запощу и удаленные комментарии, очень уж они замечательные.

Comment: Nikolay Ershov: ...Что общего между "блуд" и "блядь"? Старославянское блѫдъ — это именно "блуд", он же — этимологически — "błąd" (который произносится "буонд", между прочим, а не так, как вы, кажется, подумали), из праславянского *blǫdъ. "Блядь" — она блѧдь, с малым юсом. Тот же корень, другая ступень вокализма. Если бы в польском было точно соответствующее слово, оно выглядело бы как blędź. А что касается смысла, все индоевропейские корни обозначают действие, поэтому первично тут "блуждать" в самом повседневном смысле, а остальные уже переносные.

Comment: Yellow Sky: Вы всё правильно пишете, только одна маленькая поправочка: хоть и в польском, и в старославянском по два одинаковых носовых звука, между ними нет однозначного соответствия, в польском произошла мена носовых, оба праславянских юса в польском перешли в ą /ǫ/ в древнепольских долгих слогах (в основном в современных закрытых), и в ę в древнепольских кратких слогах (в основном в современных открытых): dąb ­– dęby (дуб – дубы). Поэтому, если бы в польском было слово, точно соответствующее блѧдь с малым юсом, оно выглядело бы как blądź. А в остальном вы правы.

Answer (score -4):

из иврита БЛИЯД (בלי יד) - без руки (это дословный перевод). В более широком понятии - человек (в данном случае - женщина), которой ни кто не подаст руки в знак не уважения, или для того, что-бы на неё опереться.